# programmatically turn on "do not disturb"

Tags: ios

In iOS 6, you can switch on/off the "do not disturb mode". Is there a possibility to do that from an app? Or is there at least a way to find out if it is set?

Comment: Refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976453/can-you-programmatically-toggle-do-not-disturb-mode-in-ios-8-w-swift

Comment: Refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976453/can-you-programmatically-toggle-do-not-disturb-mode-in-ios-8-w-swift

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the exact answer, but I would recommend you research the internal settings URLs that Apple has (prefs:root=) which is documented here:
http://www.techwithintent.com/2011/11/force-an-ios-5-device-into-airplane-mode-with-a-single-click/

Please note - when referencing these URLs the user will be switched OUT of your app, so this is a way to access/toggle different settings, but it is not really programatic.

Comment: good one, I haven't heard about that! unfortunately, it is disabled since iOS 5.1...

Comment: How would one activate these settings/URLs from *within* a native app?