# How to check for Do Not Disturb in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Currently I have a Xamarin Forms application which we use to produce an iOS application (Android will follow at a later date). Within this app we play sound but would like to be able to detect if the device is in Do Not Disturb mode to avoid playing the sound.

I've had a good search around for an answer but can't seem to find a solution within Xamarin.

The linked article highlights how to access using Swift but I cannot get a working solution in Xamarin if anyone could assist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613303/7462031