# Can you programmatically toggle Do Not Disturb mode in iOS 8 (w/ Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Doing some research on this, it looks like you couldn't toggle Do Not Disturb mode in iOS 6 or 7. Wondering if you can do it in iOS 8. I can't find anything in Apple's docs

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I would be shocked if Apple let apps modify that setting.

Comment: @Andrew Why? It would be super useful!

Comment: For example, I develop an app where the user should learn for a bit of a time and don't get disrupted, only because a friend updated his Facebook status or a Whatsapp Group discusses super useless things

Comment: It could be overused. Imagine one app just turned on the dnd mode and another one disabled it. But I do agree we should have the ability to access information about that, in that case, you could at least notify the user to turn it off or on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This functionality would be outside of the sandbox that Apple puts each application in. Contact between apps and contact outside of the sandbox is very restricted. One example that Apple lets you get away with is turning on the flashlight, but like AirPlane mode, Do Not Disturb (should be) is restricted. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) is some more information on the the sandbox.

Comment: Also you can toggle the screen brightness to right?

Answer (score 16):

Although the correct answer is "no at the moment you cannot", saying it is because of sandboxing is misleadings. Most of the things you do on iOS when you use Apple provided SDKs are basically Apple sanctioned circumventions of the sandbox.

The correct answer is, no you cannot because Apple does not allow it and has not yet published and SDK to allow this.