# Access Do Not Disturb From iOS App

Tags: ios

I've been googling around and I haven't seen just a clear answer to this issue. Is there away to access "Do Not Disturb" from another application or service? An example, if I was wanting to setup multiple "Do Not Disturb" scheduled events. This would not replace the current "Do Not Disturb" functionality of the device, but toggle the on/off for the users desired times.

So far what I've read suggest this isn't possible. Apple doesn't want an application having access to global settings. I wasn't sure if someone knew about a work around or if Apple has changed their policy on this matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [programmatically turn on "do not disturb"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527838/programmatically-turn-on-do-not-disturb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no public API that allows you to enable/disable "Do Not Disturb", and even if you find a way to do it your app will be rejected.